# Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid for new ID

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to increment an ID when customer details have been added, a function has been called within the save button to increment ID, but as the title says it cannot convert string "" to double, any advice on how to fix?

```
Function getnewID(ByRef startposition As Integer, ByVal fieldlength As Integer)
    Dim highestvalue As Integer
    Dim fileData() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Dir$(_CLfilename))
    If UBound(fileData) = 0 Then
        Return 1
    Else
        highestvalue = Int(Trim(Mid(FileData(1), startposition, fieldlength - 1)))
        Dim length As Integer = UBound(fileData)
        For I = 1 To length
            If highestvalue < Int(Trim(Mid(fileData(I), startposition, fieldlength - 1))) Then
                highestvalue = Int(Trim(Mid(fileData(I), startposition, fieldlength - 1)))
            End If
        Next I
        highestvalue = Convert.ToInt16(highestvalue) + 1
        Return highestvalue
    End If
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: What is input string? Have you tried to debug your programm?

Comment: have tried debugging to no success, the input string currently is at 1.

Comment: At least you should be able to see which string is empty.

Comment: Thats the thing there is no string empty, thats why i'm having problems with it

Comment: Which row? What is the stack trace?

Comment: why convert int to int? highestvalue = Convert.ToInt16(highestvalue) + 1

Comment: change highestvalue = Int(Trim(Mid(FileData(1), startposition, fieldlength - 1))) to: Dim checking as string = Trim(Mid(FileData(1), startposition, fieldlength - 1)) (next line) highestvalue = Int(checking). Is checking an empty string in some point? Maybe just skip it/ that empty line. Could be the last line?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a ReadAllLines you could do readline and then as it goes through each line have

```
highestvalue +=1
```

in the loop so for each line setting it to however many lines. ReadLine() is just as quick as reading all.